# In BAZEL, Is there a way to prevent dependency C/C++ headers from being propagated to dependent library?

Tags: c++, c, bazel

For example:
`lib_a` is an internal library. It exposes interface header `alpha.h`.

`lib_b` is an API library.  It includes `alpha.h` in `beta.c` and exposes interface header `beta.h` which does not include `alpha.h`.

`exe_c` is a test app that utilizes `lib_b`.  Since it is "external" to API library `lib_b`, it should not have access to internal library `lib_a`'s headers, namely `alpha.h`.

Now, is there a way to prevent the include path of `alpha.h` from being added to `exe_c` 's compilation command-line?

Comment: To clarify - are you saying there’s a *.h file that’s #including a *.c file? Also, looked at wrapping stuff in #ifdef?

Comment: @Dai It is the other way around. `.c` `#include` `.h`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update 5/24/22: Bazel added an [implementation_deps](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.implementation_deps) feature.

This is possible with a custom rule and macro.

Here's how you can write a macro `my_cc_library` so that you can do something like this

```
my_cc_library(
    name = "b",
    hdrs = [
        "b.h",
    ],
    srcs = [
        "b.cc",
    ]
    impl_deps = [
        "//a:a",
    ],
)
```

And targets that depend on `b` will not be able to include headers from dependency `a`.

### Step 1

Add a custom rule that takes a base library and forms a new [CcInfo](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/3.3.0/skylark/lib/CcInfo.html#CcInfo) provider with only the headers you want to expose.

```
def _my_cc_slim_library(ctx):
  cc_info = ctx.attr.base_library[CcInfo]
  compilation_ctx = cc_info.compilation_context

  compilation_ctx_p = cc_common.create_compilation_context(
      headers = depset(direct=ctx.files.hdrs),
      includes = compilation_ctx.includes,
      quote_includes = compilation_ctx.quote_includes,
  )

  dep_cc_infos = [dep[CcInfo] for dep in ctx.attr.deps]

  cc_info_p = cc_common.merge_cc_infos(
      cc_infos = [
          CcInfo(
              compilation_context = compilation_ctx_p,
              linking_context = cc_info.linking_context,
          )
      ] + dep_cc_infos,
  )
  
  return [cc_info_p]

my_cc_slim_library = rule(
    implementation = _my_cc_slim_library,
    attrs = {
        "base_library": attr.label(mandatory=True, providers = [CcInfo]),
        "hdrs": attr.label_list(allow_files=True),
        "deps": attr.label_list(providers = [CcInfo]),
    },
)
```

### Step 2

Add the custom macro `my_cc_library`. This macro will create a base library and then use the rule `my_cc_slim_library` to strip out the unwanted header dependencies.

```
def my_cc_library(
    name,
    hdrs = [],
    deps = [],
    impl_deps = [],
    **kwargs):
  native.cc_library(
      name = name + "-base",
      hdrs = hdrs,
      deps = deps + impl_deps,
      **kwargs)
  my_cc_slim_library(
      name = name,
      hdrs = hdrs,
      base_library = name + "-base",
      deps = deps,
  )
```

### Example

Now here's how to use it in the example.

`bazel/my_cc_library.bzl` <- contains the custom rule and macro

`a/a.h`

```
int do_a();
```

`a/a.cc`

```
#include "a/a.h"

int do_a() {
  return 1;
}
```

`a/BUILD`

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

cc_library(
    name = "a",
    hdrs = [
        "a.h",
    ],
    srcs = [
        "a.cc",
    ],
)
```

`b/b.h`

```
int do_b();
```

`b/b.cc`

```
#include "a/a.h"

int do_b() {
  return do_a() + 2;
}
```

`b/BUILD`

```
load(
    "//bazel:my_cc_library.bzl",
    "my_cc_library",
)

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

my_cc_library(
    name = "b",
    hdrs = [
        "b.h",
    ],
    srcs = [
        "b.cc",
    ],
    impl_deps = [
        "//a:a",
    ],
)
```

`main.cc`

```
#include <iostream>

// #include "a/a.h"   <- this would cause an error
#include "b/b.h"

int main() {
  std::cout << do_b() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

`BUILD`

```
cc_binary(
    name = "exe",
    srcs = [
        "main.cc",
    ],
    deps = [
        "//b:b",
    ],
)
```

Comment: This is a lot of effort but I see how this could work now that I have a lot more knowledge on `bazel` than when I asked the question.  Thanks for posting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it looks like there is no way to prevent this in Bazel at the moment.

From https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#hdrs:

> For cc_library rules, headers in hdrs comprise the public interface of
>   the library and can be directly included both from the files in hdrs
>   and srcs of the library itself as well as from files in hdrs and srcs
>   of cc_* rules that list the library in their deps. Headers in srcs
>   must only be directly included from the files in hdrs and srcs of the
>   library itself.

and

> Unfortunately Bazel currently cannot distinguish between direct and
>   transitive inclusions, so **it cannot detect error cases where a file
>   illegally includes a header directly that is only allowed to be
>   included transitively**. For example, Bazel would not complain if in the
>   example above foo.cc directly includes baz.h. This would be illegal,
>   because foo does not directly depend on baz. Currently, no error is
>   produced in that case, but such error checking may be added in the
>   future.

Example project:

```
.
├── BUILD
├── c.cpp
├── lib_b
│   ├── b.cpp
│   ├── b.h
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── lib_a
│       ├── a.cpp
│       ├── a.h
│       └── BUILD
└── WORKSPACE
```

./WORKSPACE (empty)
./lib_b/BUILD

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")
cc_library(
    name="lib_b",
    srcs=["b.cpp"],
    hdrs=["b.h"],
    deps=["//lib_b/lib_a"],
    visibility=["//visibility:public"]
)
```

./lib_b/lib_a/BUILD

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")
cc_library(
    name="lib_a",
    srcs=["a.cpp"],
    hdrs=["a.h"],
    visibility=["//lib_b:__subpackages__"]
)
```

./lib_b/lib_a/a.h

```
#pragma once
void a();
```

./lib_b/lib_a/a.cpp

```
void a(){}
```

./lib_b/b.cpp

```
void b(){}
```

./lib_b/b.h

```
#pragma once
#include "lib_a/a.h"
void b();
```

./c.cpp

```
#include "lib_b/b.h"
#include "lib_b/lib_a/a.h" // <--- this is illegal
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

./BUILD

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary")
cc_binary(
    name="exc_c",
    srcs=["c.cpp"],
    deps=["//lib_b"]
)
```

Bazel builds and runs `exc_c` without warnings

```
> $ bazel run exc_c                                                                                                                                               
INFO: Analyzed target //:exc_c (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:exc_c up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/exc_c
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.219s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

Comment: "exposes interface header beta.h which does not include alpha.h" <- there's no transitive include in the problem statement

Comment: @RyanBurn I think what laurenz meant when mentioning "transitive include" was that bazel's stock rules treated all includes as transitive.  Thus it did not support specifying non-transitive includes like I asked.